# Grails unresolved dependencies

Tags: grails

I know that there are a million similar problems but I have gone through most of them and still have not managed to solve this issue.

These plugins are problematic

```
runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"
compile ':twitter-bootstrap:2.3.1'
compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"
compile ":grails-melody:1.56.0"
```

Repositories I use

```
grailsPlugins()
grailsHome()
grailsCentral()
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release"
mavenRepo "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external"
```

Running

```
grails dependency-report
```

just tells me that these plugins are not found. I've searched GRADLE_HOME dirs and they do not exist in there but they do exist in [here](https://grails.org/plugin) so they should still be found?

I've also tried `grails install-plugin plugin_name` but this gives the same error `unresolved dependencies`.

I have GrailsMelodyConfig.groovy and other .groovy files generated from a previous build but can't get it to work now.

Using grails 2.2.1 and groovy 2.0.7

Comment: Even tought I've been struggling with this for almost 3 hours it is always a good idea to post here because right after posting I seem to find a solution.

Found the repo link somewhere, took the zips and manually added them to the plugins folder. Maybe it is going to help someone else.
http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/org/grails/plugins/

Comment: Although if someone has ideas how to add/download the plugins using only BuildConfig.groovy that would be great as I need to deploy it to a server later.